# How to insert IP address in table?

Tags: php, sql

I'm coding an admin page where I keep track of users/visitors. I have some code so far, but I need to add ip addresses from the users/visitors to the table as well. This is my code, everything gets added to the database table except for ip address. The table is users4project and column is ip address with the int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL I created the table in phpmyadmin.

```
<?php
function visitor($record) {
    // my database info
    $db_host = "";
    $db_username = ""; 
    $db_password = "";
    $db_name = "";
    $db_table = "ipusers4project";
    $counter_page = "access_page";
    $counter_field = "access_counter";

    $db = mysqli_connect ($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name) 
        or die("Host or database not accessible");
        
    $sql_call = "INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (".$counter_page.", 
        ".$counter_field.") VALUES ('".$record."', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ".$counter_field." = ".$counter_field." + 1";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql_call) or die("Error while entering");
        
    $sql_call = "SELECT ".$counter_field. " FROM ".$db_table." WHERE ".$counter_page. " = '".$record. "'";
    $sql_result = mysqli_query($db, $sql_call) or die("SQL request failed ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
    $x = $row[$counter_field];
        
    mysqli_close($db);
    return $x;
}
?>
<?php
$ipadress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO
    ipusers4project
    ( ipadress )
    VALUES
    ( '$ipadress')";
?>
```

EDIT: On index.php I have this code:

```
<?php
$page_name = "index.php";
?>
<title><?php echo $page_name; ?></title>
<?php
include "webcounter.php";
$access_number = visitor($page_name);

?>
```

Comment: Show us the actual as-implemented code, and tell us which line is #17, please.

Comment: `$ipaddress` is not the same as `$ipadress`

Comment: @ChrisWhite Thank you, the error is gone now! But it doesn't add any data to the ipadress column in the database? Only to the other columns.

Comment: @LindaKaltrinaAndersson Fixing that typo shouldn't fix the "unspected" error. That's usually because you forgot the `;` at the end of the previous line.

Comment: You should parameterize your query. I also would recommend storing in a different format so you can use functions on the value later. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton

Comment: @Barmar could you please specify? I don't understand where I forgot the ;

Comment: I don't see where you did, either.

Comment: But misspelling a variable usually causes an "Undefined variable" error, not a "Parse error".

Comment: You can also get that syntax error if you forget a `.` that's needed for concatenation. But the code you posted doesn't need that, since you substitute the variable inside a string. All I can guess is that you didn't post the actual code.

Comment: Yes, during your answers I worked on the code and got different errors. I now edited my question, sorry! But now you can see what I have a problem with. :)

Comment: @Barmar I have edited my question :)

Comment: Which line is line #17?

Comment: I don't have the file left that had that error. But I don't have any errors now and the code works well and the other columns add data. Just not ip adress, it doesn't add an ip adress to the column @Barmar

Comment: Then you must have changed something else when you fixed the typo.

Comment: Where is the code that calls the `visitor()` function?

Comment: it's in my index file and looks like this @Barmar:

<?php
    $page_name = "index.php";
    ?>
<title><?php echo $page_name; ?></title>
<?php
    include "webcounter.php";
    $access_number = visitor($page_name);
    ?>

Comment: You never execute the SQL that's supposed to put the IP address in the table.

Comment: Ok! What should I add, how do I execute it?

Comment: @Barmar I tried adding $sql->execute(); to the code I just send you. But then I get the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in (myfile) on line 11. Line 11 is $sql->execute();

Comment: You need to execute it the same way you execute the SQL inside the `visitor()` function. You have to call `mysqli_connect()`, and then call `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Maybe you should just move that inside the `visitor()` function, so you don't have to make another connection.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I would like to move it inside the visitor() function, but since I am new to php could you help me with how I implement it in the function?

Comment: Is it supposed to be in the same row as the record that `visitor()` is adding, or is it supposed to be in a row by itself as you've shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this as another column in the row that `visitor()` is adding.

```
<?php
function visitor($record) {
    // my database info
    $db_host = "";
    $db_username = ""; 
    $db_password = "";
    $db_name = "";
    $db_table = "ipusers4project";
    $counter_page = "access_page";
    $counter_field = "access_counter";
    $ipadress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $db = mysqli_connect ($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name) 
        or die("Host or database not accessible");

    $sql_call = "INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (".$counter_page.", 
        ".$counter_field.", ipadress) VALUES ('".$record."', 1, '$ipadress') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ".$counter_field." = ".$counter_field." + 1, ipadress = VALUES(ipadress)";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql_call) or die("Error while entering");

    $sql_call = "SELECT ".$counter_field. " FROM ".$db_table." WHERE ".$counter_page. " = '".$record. "'";
    $sql_result = mysqli_query($db, $sql_call) or die("SQL request failed ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
    $x = $row[$counter_field];

    mysqli_close($db);
    return $x;
}
?>
```